# Configuring MSDynamics landing page for Administrator user

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In Ms Dynamics,I am having two different users.Norma CRM user and Administrator.When administrator user login,then Ms Dynamics redirect it to Admin dashboard which is completely fine.
I am looking for setting/configuration where administrator can set CRM dashboard as default for Administrator user,so that when administrator login then he is taken to CRM dashboard instead of admin dashboard.

**Can it configured per admin level?**

Answer (score 0):

It can be configured per user:

[image]